# Which Framework and Model is Best for Multi-Object Detection Tasks on Low Power Devices in 2023?

Tags: machine-learning, python

**TL;DR: What are the best frameworks and models for real-time multi-object detection on a low-power device in 2023?**

I'm starting a project requiring multi-object detection and/or segmentation. While I've had some experience with PyTorch for single-object classification and TensorFlow for basic object detection as tests, the landscape for multi-object detection seems vast and a bit daunting and the ones tailored for single-board computers (I could find) are comparatively uncommon.

I'd like to make an informed choice about the most suitable framework and model, especially given the specifics of my task and available hardware.

**Project Details:**

- Goal: Multi-object detection and, if possible, segmentation.
- Data: Images with 3-6 different object classes. Real-time
  segmentation is a bonus but not mandatory.
- Input: Live webcam feed aiming for >20 FPS inference.
- Dataset: Self-annotated with Label Studio for bounding boxes.
- Available Hardware for Inference:

  - Rockchip RK3588: 6 Tops (INT4/INT8/INT16/FP16).
  - 2x Google Edge TPU: 2x4 Tops(INT8) (Supports TensorFlow Lite).

Given that the Google Edge TPU supports TensorFlow Lite (and understanding that models from various frameworks can be converted to TensorFlow and then to TensorFlow Lite)

**Which framework and model would be most strategic to invest time in learning and implementing for a SBC in 2023?**

The information during my research was quite contradicting and a lot of repositories seem inactive. From my own search, I came to the result that MobileNetV3 with SSD or an older Yolo version would be a possible approach but as my knowledge about machine learning is quite limited therefore I cannot make an informed decision.

It's crucial for me to have access to comprehensive and high-quality documentation. I also prefer solutions that don't require extensive low-level implementation. Specifically, I'm not comfortable with manipulating input and output layers or defining custom loss functions. Therefore, at this stage, I'd like to avoid extensive customization of the models I use.

As an example of performance [Edge-Yolo ran with 30FPS on an RK3588](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/13/7/4402), this level of performance would be perfect for my application.

---

Extra Questions:

1. Dual Model Approach: I'm considering running two separate models.
   One on the SBC for real-time object detection and another on the
   Edge TPUs for object segmentation. Does this make sense?
2. Annotation Software Compatibility: I've used Label Studio for annotations, but its export format didn't seem directly compatible with TensorFlow. Which annotation tool would be most seamless for the recommended framework/model? Ideally, I'd like something self-hostable.